# Macro for calculating specific cells

Tags: excel

I am trying to make a button so I can recalculate a certain area inside of my worksheet. However after having looked at several tutorials I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
Sub ReloadPlanet()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E9:H27").Calculate
End Sub
```

Any feedback as to what I am doing wrong?

***edit***

**Here is a bit more detail on the sheet itself:**

[image: Screenshot of the area I want to refresh]

Each of the commands I want refresh are VLOOKUP commands

Comment: We would need to know what you're recalculating, and why those cells are not normally calculating. You really haven't thought through this question. Have a read of [ask] and [mcve] and see if they help you to edit this question and make it easier for us to answer.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail I just added some more detail to the post and I hope that makes it easier to anwer

Comment: `VLOOKUP` will automatically update. You don't need to do anything. What makes you think it's not updating?

Comment: I want to stop it from automatically recalculating (so I put the calculation to the manual setting) and rather I would like just those series of cell to recalculate on command (preferably by means of a button/shortcut) without the whole sheet being recalculated.

Comment: And there it is - you really haven't thought this question through. Don't you think that telling us that you put Excel into manual calculation mode was important?

Comment: You really need to give us a [mcve] by tell us the steps required to reproduce this problem on our computers.